# iptables ERROR target

Tags: iptables, netfilter

When I list the `iptables` rules for `filter` table with `iptables -t filter -L -vvv --line-numbers` command, then I see entry numbers from 0 to 124 under the debug output. Last entry is following:

```
Entry 124 (42880):
SRC IP: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0
DST IP: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0
Interface: `'/................to `'/................
Protocol: 0
Flags: 00
Invflags: 00
Counters: 0 packets, 0 bytes
Cache: 00000000
Target name: `ERROR' [64]
error=`ERROR'
```

When do packets end up in this `ERROR` target?

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll find your answer in the leading comment of `libip4tc.c`:

```
/* Library which manipulates firewall rules.  Version 0.1. */

/* Architecture of firewall rules is as follows:
 *
 * Chains go INPUT, FORWARD, OUTPUT then user chains.
 * Each user chain starts with an ERROR node.
 * Every chain ends with an unconditional jump: a RETURN for user chains, 
 * and a POLICY for built-ins.
 */
```